# Is this "too many nested blocks"?

Tags: php, netbeans

Netbeans keeps giving me annoying notifications for "too many nested blocks" and suggesting I introduce a new function, but is the following really bad practice?

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
if ($sth->execute())
  {
  if ($sth->rowCount())
    {
    while ($row = $sth->fetch())
      {
      // Read the database here
      }
    }
  else
    {
    // Handle no result case here
    }
  }
else
  {
  // Catch query failure here - Is this bit necessary if I'm confident the query is OK?
  }
```

So it seems I'm already at Netbeans recommended nested block limit every time I write an SQL query - could I safely make this slicker?  I know it is only a coding "hint", but I want to check I'm not doing anything drastically stupid :)

Comment: such approach is more than fine when we are talking about SQL execution and handling. btw - you have missing closing curly bracket before last `else`.

Comment: You can turn those notifications off if they are annoying you that much. Go **Tools** > **Options**. Click **Editor** and select the **Hints** tab. Make sure PHP is selected as the language. For this specific notification, you want to un-check **Nested Blocks in Functions**

Comment: Thanks @ImClarky, but I was asking if I should pay any attention to them - I already know how to turn them off if needs be, but wanted to check I'm not just sweeping the problem under the rug, so to speak :)

Comment: mitkosoft - thanks, it was only for example purposes, but I've made the edit :)  So it seems like quite a stupid hint then - whenever it is enabled half of my project will always be full of these "hints" due to very basic code.  I will turn it off!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's not too bad, but, depending on your preference, you can first handle 'error' cases, avoiding nested `if` statements, something like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

if (!$sth->execute) {
  throw new Exception("Things went bad with the query!");
}

if (!$sth->rowCount()) {
  // either throw an exception if you always expect to have results
  // or handle the case in whatever way you need
}

while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {
  do_something_nice($row);
}
```

If there are many things that can go wrong, or many ways to handle one specific case, then this would be a bit nicer way instead of having `if() { if() { if() { if() { ... }}}}` mess.

Comment: Brilliant!  This is exactly what I was hoping for - I can now leave the best practice hints enabled, and actually follow them in the majority of cases, so the one or two errors remaining actually have some meaning now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also change or disable the warning in "Tools/Options/Editor" in the "Hints" Tab, language PHP "Nested Blocks in Functions".

Comment: The question wasn't asking about disabling the notice.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30462759)